# Start Sidekiq on system boot up. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, sidekiq, upstart

I read entire Internet, but can't do this. Need start Sidekiq on VDS (Ubuntu 14.04) boot up. I found and use this:

```
# /etc/init/sidekiq.conf - Sidekiq config

# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+.  It
# allows you to manage multiple Sidekiq instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See workers.conf for how to manage all Sidekiq instances at once.
#
# Save this config as /etc/init/sidekiq.conf then manage sidekiq with:
#   sudo start sidekiq index=0
#   sudo stop sidekiq index=0
#   sudo status sidekiq index=0
#
# Hack Upstart's reload command to 'quiet' Sidekiq:
#
#   sudo reload sidekiq index=0
#
# or use the service command:
#   sudo service sidekiq {start,stop,restart,status}
#

description "Sidekiq Background Worker"

start on startup

#start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

#start on startup


# change to match your deployment user
 setuid me
 setgid me
 env HOME=/home/me

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

# TERM is sent by sidekiqctl when stopping sidekiq. Without declaring these as
# normal exit codes, it just respawns.
normal exit 0 TERM

# Older versions of Upstart might not support the reload command and need
# this commented out.
reload signal USR1

instance $index

    script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  # Pick your poison :) Or none if you're using a system wide installed Ruby.
  # rbenv
  # source /home/apps/.bash_profile
  # OR
  # source /home/apps/.profile
  # OR system:
  # source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
  #
  rvm
  source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm

  # Logs out to /var/log/upstart/sidekiq.log by default

  cd /var/www/vk_c_watcher/code
  exec bundle exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
EOT
end script
```

After adding that I can start Sidekiq with  `start sidekiq app="/var/www/vk_c_watcher/code" index=0`. But on reboot no Sidekiq in process list.

Comment: nobilik, did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @JaredMenard not yet, but think to experiment with runlevels. I was busy with other things.

Comment: If I come up with a solution, I will post an answer here.

Comment: @JaredMenard Hi, solved! [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sidekiq/Mmgged4cqQs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Mike Perham for help. I simply used wrong script. With [this script](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/upstart/workers.conf) Sidekiq starts at startup.

Answer (score 0):

`startup` event is fired at the very start of system, no writeable filesystem nor network is accessible at that moment, probably it does try to start, but crashes and even cannot log this.

Run it a bit later, for example at runlevel 2 or some custom event that fires when other dependencies have started (redis, your database, etc.)

Also comment-out `# rvm` back again, that was not a command, but a label for next line with `source ...`.

Comment: for `#rvm` I'm already see it. Thanks.  Other things will try.